# Need a sql efficient query

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan, groupwise-maximum

I have around 6 million rows in the table and I am query the table with below query.

```
SELECT * FROM FD_CPC_HISTORICAL_DATA WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM FD_CPC_HISTORICAL_DATA WHERE fb_ads_account_id=1462257067274960 AND created_at BETWEEN '2019-12-13 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-13 23:59:59' GROUP BY source_text) \G
```

I have created index for fb_ads_account_id, created_at, source_text. id is primary key.

My question is why this query takes around 9 seconds to get the result even though I have created indexes?

Is there any other way to create this query more efficient?

**Here is mysql explain command explanation**

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what index(es) you have; please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT hd.*
FROM FD_CPC_HISTORICAL_DATA hd
WHERE hd.id IN (SELECT MAX(hd2.id)
                FROM FD_CPC_HISTORICAL_DATA hd2
                WHERE hd2.fb_ads_account_id = 1462257067274960 AND
                      hd2.created_at >= '2019-12-13' AND 
                      hd2.created_at < '2019-12-14'
                GROUP BY source_text
               );
```

I would recommend writing this as:

```
SELECT hd.*
FROM FD_CPC_HISTORICAL_DATA hd
WHERE hd.fb_ads_account_id = 1462257067274960 AND
      hd.id = (SELECT MAX(hd2.id)
               FROM FD_CPC_HISTORICAL_DATA hd2
               WHERE hd2.fb_ads_account_id = hd.hd.fb_ads_account_id AND
                     hd2.source_text = hd.source_tx AND
                     hd2.created_at >= '2019-12-13' AND 
                     hd2.created_at < '2019-12-14'
               );
```

For this query, you want an index on `FD_CPC_HISTORICAL_DATA(fb_ads_account_id, source_text,created_at)`.

Comment: thank you. is it a composite index or something like that? I'm just asking because I am not much expertise on indexes :)

Comment: @SandunPerera . . . An index with more than one key is called a *composite index*.  So the proposed index is a composite index.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got a dramatic enhancement with this.

Comment: @sandunPerera . . . You accepted another answer.  Does that mean that answer provided better performance?

Answer (score 1):

This query probably can be performed without a subquery against the same table ie:

`SELECT * FROM FD_CPC_HISTORICAL_DATA
WHERE fb_ads_account_id=1462257067274960 
AND created_at BETWEEN '2019-12-13 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-13 23:59:59' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`

if you want the max ID. Or something similar, I am not sure you need the GROUP BY to get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you. group by should be there because there are multiple rows with same source so that need to get the latest one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the index is exactly what you need. The part in the `EXPLAIN` that confuses me is the (guesstimated?) amount of rows from the subquery being so different from the one in the primary query.

To be honest, I'm not very familiar with MYSQL, but in MSSQL I would give it a try to first dump the results from the subquery into a temporary table, put a unique clustered index on it and then select everything from the original table joined to said temporary table on the ID column. (Don't use IN, use JOIN as there can't be any doubles in the temporary table)

This might also show where all the time is being spent.
My guess is that this is mostly a statistics issue but I don't really know how to force an update of the statistics on the index in MYSQL.
(there is some talk about `FLUSH TABLE` in https://dzone.com/articles/updating-innodb-table-statistics-manually but it seems to come with some downsides too, use with care)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. this helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  f.*
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  source_text, MAX(created_at) AS mx
            FROM  FD_CPC_HISTORICAL_DATA
            WHERE  fb_ads_account_id=1462257067274960
              AND  created_at >= '2019-12-13'
              AND  created_at  < '2019-12-13' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
            GROUP BY  source_text 
        ) AS x
    JOIN  FD_CPC_HISTORICAL_DATA AS f
       ON  f.account_id = x.account_id
      AND  f.source_text = x.source_text
      AND  f.created_at = x.mx
```

Then you need this composite index:

```
INDEX(account_id, source_text, created_at)  -- in this order
```

If this does not quite work because of duplicate entries with the same `created_at`, then a tweak may be possible.